# Questions about history of cultivation

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

Is it ok to ask questions on this site about the history of cultivation of a certain plant?
If not, is there any other SE website more appropriate for that?

The question I have in mind is: "How did amaranths arrive into [ancient Greece](http://www.appropedia.org/Original:Amaranth_Modern_Prospects_for_an_Ancient_Crop_8)", since they are from America (Aztecs)?

Comment: Also, *Amaranthus blitum*, eg, is indigeneous to the Mediterranean region, and has been consumed as food since ancient times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although there exists a dedicated [History of science and mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) SE site, the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) sites sometimes have questions about the history of a symbol, of a theorem. Those are quite interesting, to grow connections, rise interest. While I am not a high-level gardener, I believe such questions could be appropriate, and could be better by linking to other questions related to that plant.